# Segmentation fault when passing a structure to unordered_map

Tags: c++, struct, segmentation-fault, unordered-map

Hi I ran into an error a couple of days back. The code is not the same but is similar to what is listed below:

```
     struct AB{

          vector<int> * temp;

          AB(){
              temp = new vector<int>;

          }

          AB(const AB &other){

                     temp = new vector<int> 
                    //and I am memberwise copying other.temp to temp. (Not shown here)
          }
         ~AB(){
                      delete AB;
          }
      };
```

And in the main class I am doing this

```
      unordered_map<int, AB> mapOfAB;
      mapOfAB[0].temp->push_back(1);
```

This is giving me a segmentation fault, but if I am making temp as a stack(non-dynamic) variable, it runs fine. I hope I am specific enough.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace for the crash?

Comment: I already changed the code and corrected the implementation actually. This was more of an afterthought

Comment: @Phelodas Wait, so, is your problem solved or...?

Comment: Yes it is working. I changed temp to a stack variable and it worked. I was just wondering why this would happen

Comment: Why in the world are you storing a pointer to a vector?  That is not how a vector is intended to be used.  It allocates its memory dynamically, the vector object itself is small.  Don't use a pointer.

Comment: @Phelodas: You didn't change it to a "stack" variable, though I understand why you would think of it that way.  If I `new` up an instance of your class the vector lives on the heap. The point is that the vector itself is not dynamically allocated forcing you to clean it up as it's destructor will run when your object goes out of scope.

Comment: @Phelodas: Think of it this way; you have written a class to implement the RAII pattern, cleaning up its internal resources when it leaves its scope via the destructor.  What if I dynamically allocate an instance of your class?  Well, I am circumventing your design and your destructor will never run.  In turn, the vector will be leaked as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a raw pointer, and you do not have an assignment operator. You have violated the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29).